# laravel permission migrate not create table

Tags: mysql, laravel, permissions, migration, rollback

I have one problem.
I created permission using spaite and composer require command.
In migrations directory there is create_permission file exist.
So, i migrated but table not created.
i discovered this error when i rollback migration using php artisan migrate:rollback or php artisan migrate:reset.
what is the problem?
i used laravel 8
And other laravel 8 project create table but now current project is same laravel 8 but not create table and has error when rollback.
also, i can see to be created personal_access_token table in current project.
what is reason?
Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the following steps when installing this composer package(spatie or laravel-permission) to laravel:

Install composer package(laravel-permission or spatie) to Laravel:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
],
```

We can also custom changes on Spatie package, so if you also want to changes then you can fire bellow command and get config file in config/permission.php and migration files.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider"
```

Now you can see permission.php file and one migrations. so you can run migration using following command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Spatie package provide it's in-built middleware that way we can use it simply and that is display as bellow:
So, we have to add middleware in Kernel.php file this way :
app/Http/Kernel.php

```
....
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
]
....
```